# Change Color of selection Angular Material Table with selection

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

How to change the color of the selector in the angular material table with selection [image]

Answer (score 0):

Add additional Color argument to pass the theme name 
Example: `<mat-checkbox color="primary"></mat-checkbox>`

Answer (score 0):

Works for all normal check-boxes as well as indeterminate ones in the header.

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background,
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-indeterminate .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: green !important; // Example color green 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<mat-checkbox color="primary"></mat-checkbox>
```

css

```
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: red;
}
```